# SELECT after specific row with non-sequential (uuid) primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid, postgresql-13

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    inserted_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
    -- other fields
);
```

How could I retrieve `n` rows after a specific `id`, ordered by `inserted_at` ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how your query is supposed to be working.  The `where` clause would seem to be filtering `id`s that are less than the specified id, not the time associated with that id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm confused too, I am unable to make my query work again. I think that because I picked a uuid beginning with `f` for manual tests I was unable to detect that it filtered value BELOW that and not after. Apologies !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve n rows after a specific id, ordered by inserted_at.

I am expecting something like this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.inserted_at > (select u2.inserted_at from users u2 where u2.id = 'f4ae4105-1afb-4ba6-a2ad-4474c9bae483')
order by u.inserted_at
limit 10;
```

For this, you want one additional index on `users(inserted_at)`.